# why am I getting an error with dbSeeChanges

Tags: vba, ms-access

I converted an access db to a ODBC backend and I needed to add the dbSeeChanges to a line of the code, but when I added the code I got another error on the login screen Err 3001 Invalid Argument

This is the code I use, and I am absolutely not a professional coder, I am just trying to teach myself how to code and I am tinkering around.

```vb
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

    On Error GoTo cmdLogin_ClickErr
    
    If Len(Me.txtUserName) = 9 And Len(Me.txtPassword) = 1 Then
        TempVars.Add "UserName", "Developer"
        TempVars.Add "Password", "1"
        TempVars.Add "Admin", "-1"
    Else
        Dim rs As Recordset
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From TLKPeople Where Username =  '" & Me.txtUserName & "' And Password = '" & Me.txtPassword & "'", dbSeeChanges)
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            TempVars.Add "UserName", rs!UserName.Value
            TempVars.Add "Password", rs!Password.Value
            TempVars.Add "Admin", rs!Admin.Value
            TempVars.Add "ReadOnly", rs!ReadOnly.Value
            TempVars.Add "StdUser", rs!STDUser.Value
            TempVars.Add "OpsUser", rs!OpsUser.Value
        Else
            MsgBox "Your login as failed!", vbOKOnly, "Login Failed"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Password* is a reserved word is Access SQL, so:

```vb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From TLKPeople Where Username = '" & Me.txtUserName & "' And [Password] = '" & Me.txtPassword & "'", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I didn't know that. I altered the code to above, and when I try to login, I get Err3001: Invalid Argument. I am figuring my code is still not good

Comment: I stumbled over this and it fixed my issues
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From TLKPeople Where Username = '" & Me.txtUserName & "' And [Password] = '" & Me.txtPassword & "'", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

Comment: That is correct. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciated